# Instanciation error when launching new activity from a dialog.

Tags: android

I am facing instanciation error when I luanch new activity from a dialog.

I make a dialog object from main class then show a dialog.

```
LoginDialog loginDialog = new LoginDialog(Main.this);
loginDialog.show();
```

Atfer dialog launched, dialog gets owner activity from dialog constructor.

```
public LoginDialog(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(activity);
    mActivity = new Activity();
    mActivity = activity;
}
```

when user clicks a button from dialog, it should start a new activity 
but I gets an instanciate error instread.

```
Button.OnClickListener loginTypeListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){

            case 1: 
                    if(!AutoLoginCheck.isChecked()){
                        AutoLoginChecked = false;
                    }
                    goToFbLogin();
    }

};     
void goToFbLogin(){
    Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, FacebookLogin.class);
    i.putExtra("CheckAutoLogin", AutoLoginChecked);
    mActivity.startActivity(i);
}
```

code looks fine to me but I am not sure why am I getting instanciate error.
here is my logcat. 
[image]

Can anybody tell me why am I getting instanciation error?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, FacebookLogin.class);
```

to this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FacebookLogin.class);
```